# calling a url, then performing some calculation from the data received, then calling another url

Tags: reactjs

I'm calling a url and getting some data from that, then I'm performing some calculations and then calling another url. but the hook(usestate) setform is not updating total_weight & total_amount before calling the 2nd url, but it is updating this after calling the second url. why??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5yHw.png)

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please post text, not links to images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `setState` is async, you can solve it with two approachs

1. Using a variable and not the state

```
axios.get(url)
.then(response => {
  // your code to calculate weight and amount
  const tempForm = {...form, weight, amount}
  axios.post(url, tempForm)
})
```

2. Wait until the state variable is updated using useEffect

```
axios.get(url)
.then(response => {
  // your code to calculate weight and amount
  setForm({...form, weight, amount})
})

useEffect(()=> {
  axios.post(url, form)
}, [form])
```